# Dispatcher.CheckAccess() in xamarin.forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have this class in my WPf application,now i would like to add this for xamarin.forms application,when am adding this at `Dispatcher.CheckAccess` showing error.on googling came to understand that instead of Dispatcher i have to use Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread().But do not understand how to apply this.

```
 public static void HandleInvokeRequired<T>(this T control, Action<T> action) where T : Control
    {
        //Check to see is the control is not null
        if (control == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(string.Format("Cannot execute {0} on {1}.  {1} is null.", action, control));

        if (control.Dispatcher.CheckAccess())
        {
            try
            {
                //Perform the action
                action(control);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw new Exception(string.Format("Cannot execute {0} on {1}.  {2}.", action, control, ex.Message));
            }
        }
        else
        {
            try
            {
                //Use Invoke() to invoke your action
                control.Dispatcher.Invoke(action, new object[] { control });
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw new Exception(string.Format("Cannot execute {0} on {1}.  {2}.", action, control, ex.Message));
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't find any documentation  about `CheckAccess` in `Xamarin.forms`.

Maybe it is available in desktop application, but in general it is required to operate the UI on the main thread rather than in other thread . So the code below is  enough.

```
if (control == null)
    throw new ArgumentNullException(string.Format("Cannot execute {0} on {1}.  {1} is null.", action, control));

try
{
    Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(action);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    throw new Exception(string.Format("Cannot execute {0} on {1}.  {2}.", action, control, ex.Message));
}
```

### Edit :

Action  -> Action:

Try :

```
Action newAction = () => { action(control); };
```

Or

```
Action newAction = new Action(() => { action(control); });
```

Comment: Thanks for help @Cole Xia.With this code iam getting an error at "Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(action);"- "cannot convert System.Action<T> to System.Action"

Comment: Thank you@Cole Xia